# React Native - place two items side by side

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to place an item on the right side of another, but instead it always stays on the bottom of the first item, like this:

[image]

So, right now I'm just trying to place the "TEST" text right next to that side menu.

Here's my code:

```js
<View style = {{flex: 1, width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
        height: Dimensions.get('window').height}}>

          <Workspace 
            img={require('./images/quarto.png')}/>
          
          <ScrollView>
            <Header>
              <HeaderItem img={require('./images/camera.png')}/>
              <HeaderItem img={require('./images/camera.png')}/>
              <HeaderItem img={require('./images/camera.png')}/>
              <HeaderItem img={require('./images/camera.png')}/>
            </Header>
          </ScrollView>
          
          <ScrollView style = {{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            {this.sideMenuShow()}
            <ScrollView style = {{alignSelf: 'flex-end'}}>
            <Text style = {{color: 'white'}}>TEST</Text>
            </ScrollView>
          </ScrollView>
          
          <Footer>
            <View style = {styles.logoContainerStyle}>
              <Image
                style = {styles.logoStyle}
                source = {require('./images/magicalStage.png')}
                />
            </View>
            <View 
            style = {{width: '70%', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent:'flex-end', alignItems: 'flex-end'}}>
              <TouchableOpacity>
                <Text style = {{color: 'white'}}>Workspace  </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity>
                <Text style = {{color: 'white', textAlign: 'right'}}>Catalogue</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </Footer>
        </View>
```

If it helps, the side menu code is:

```js
sideMenuShow() {
  const furnitureList = <FurnitureList />;

     if(!this.state.hideMenu) {
       
        return(
        <SideMenu> 
          <MenuButton
          source = {require('./images/left-material.png')}
          onPress = {() => this.setState({hideMenu: true})}/>
          <Text style = {{color: 'white', fontSize: 16, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Furniture</Text>
          
            <SideMenuItem 
              onPress = {() =>
                !this.state.hideList ?
                this.setState({hideList: true, hideListSofa: false, hideListBoxes: false})
                : this.setState({hideList: false})
                
                }
              text='Test'
              >
              </SideMenuItem>
              {
              this.state.hideList ? 
              <FurnitureList
              source = {require('./images/image.png')}/>
              : null
              }
        </SideMenu>
        );
        
       }
     else {
         return(
          <SmallSideMenu> 
            <MenuButton 
            source = {require('./images/right-material.png')}
            onPress = {() => this.setState({hideMenu: false})}/>
          </SmallSideMenu>
         );
     }
 }
```

I thought I'd get what I want by setting the flexDirection of the ScrollView wraping both items to 'row', but it's not working as I thought it would. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You placed your `<Text style = {{color: 'white'}}>TEST</Text>` Component inside a ScrollView.

Try to add `contentContainerStyle={{ flexDirection: 'row'}}` to the parent ScrollView or just remove the parent ScrollView. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

`{ flexDirection: 'row' }` as mentioned in above answer works.

You need to apply this to parent.

For example:
let's say your HTML equivalent looks like this:

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child1'></div>
  <div class='child2'></div>
</div>
```

then you've to apply `flexDirection: 'row'` to '`parent`' NOT '`child`'

This will make `child1` and `child2` render horizontally next to each other in same line.

Comment: You should use `className` instead of `class` because the question is about react.